# Yii2 Authclient OAuth2 авторизация по средством отправки clientId и clientSecret в заголовке запроса

Tags: php, yii2, oauth2

При расширение проекта был разработан отдельный сервис на java, для аутентификации требуется зашифровать clientId и clientSecret в Base64 и отправить в заголовке запроса. Как с помощью Authclient OAuth2 реализовать такой способ авторизации?

Как добавить в заголовок запроса что то подобное: `Authorization: Basic YhJEioIdDkRloDRqXPcsRZfvywEdCd==`?

Я смотрел документацию, но не нашел ни чего подобного, при использовании `authenticateUser()` clientId и clientSecret отправляются в теле запроса, в следствии чего авторизация не проходит.

Отказаться от шифрования нет возможности. Буду рад любым советам как реализовать такой способ авторизации на Yii2.

Comment: Посмотрите [авторизацию с помощью заголовков](https://gist.github.com/stungeye/3194428). Должно вам помочь.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Написать запрос cURL'ом для авторизации просто, но я наделся что у [Yii2 Authclient](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-authclient/doc/guide/2.2/ru) есть поддержка отправки запросов авторизации с заголовком `Authorization` из коробки.